# RDP Client with NLA asking for Password

Tags: c#, rdp, credssp, nla

Good day,
I am unfamiliar with this kind of activity so forgive any poor framing here.

I am attempting to connect with an NLA environment. We were getting error 2825, so we went and enabled EnableCredSspSupport, setting it to "true." This seems to have fixed the issue, as we no longer get the error 2825.

However, we are being prompted to enter the password, even though it's already being passed to the RPD client like so: axMsRdpClient71.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword = _logon.Password;

Question: How can I stop RDP from prompting for a Password while still having it work with NLA?

Sample C# code below:

```
private AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7 axMsRdpClient71;

axMsRdpClient71.UserName = _logon.MachineAccountName;
axMsRdpClient71.Domain = _logon.LogOnTo;

//Providing password here
axMsRdpClient71.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword = _logon.Password;

axMsRdpClient71.ColorDepth = 16;
axMsRdpClient71.AdvancedSettings2.PerformanceFlags = 111;

axMsRdpClient71.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
    
axMsRdpClient71.Server = _logon.MachineName;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayCredSharing = 1;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayCredsSource = 0;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayDomain = _logon.LogOnTo;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings.GatewayHostname = _logon.RemoteDesktopGatewayAddress;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayPassword = _logon.Password;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayPreAuthRequirement = 0;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayProfileUsageMethod = 1;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayUsageMethod = 1;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayUsername = _logon.MachineAccountName;
axMsRdpClient71.TransportSettings3.GatewayUserSelectedCredsSource = 0;

axMsRdpClient71.Connect();
```

Comment: CredSSP is incompatible with NLA, so not sure why you have enabled that. CredSSP will not use the credentials you have supplied, as the authentication is done on the actual remote machine (which is why NLA is more secure). Your issue is why NLA isn't working: try maybe `axMsRdpClient71.AdvancedSettings4.AuthenticationLevel = 2;`

Comment: Unfortunately with `axMsRdpClient71.AdvancedSettings5.AuthenticationLevel = 2;` and CredSSP Disabled, I still receive Error 2825. :(

Comment: Might be worth going through the troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/cannot-connect-rdp-azure-vm#cause Is NLA actually turned on at the remote machine? Can the local and remote machine succesfully communicate with the DC? Use Powershell `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` to confirm. Which version of Windows are they both running, are they on the latest builds? Have you done anything like messing around with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` and changing the TLS settings, or in the registry?